# Reducing tailwindcss file size in pure html css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css for a small project. I have been using tailwind via its CDN. As given it the documentation of tailwind, I have been using the following code to insert tailwind to my project -

`<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` My source code is about 10KB whereas tailwind itself is about 3MB. Therefore my site is being loaded EXTREMELY slow in the mobile phones.

But the documentation clearly says to install NodeJS as all the configuration for reducing the size of the build is using `npx`/`npm`.

But is there any method for reducing the size of the file without installing npm/npx?

Comment: There is no way to reduce the bundle size of tailwind when you use it with the CDN, because you are getting all of the tailwind CSS classes.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the clarification. But could you please upvote my question. So that if someone searches the same question. They could get a help..